# Pass a member function pointer to a method of a foreign class (EDB Lib)

Tags: c++, library, class, pointer

I'm currently working on my own arduino library and I'm becoming exasperated with the following problem: I want to store data with the extended database library (https://code.google.com/p/arduino-edb/) on a sd card. I tried to follow and adapt the instructions on [this](http://blog.brauingenieur.de/2014/01/20/extended-database-library-using-an-sd-card/) page and I gave my custom library a property "File dbFile" as well as a property "EDB db". Additionally I have to pass two function pointers to the constructor of the EDB library. So my custom library got two more properties: a writer and a reader function. My class looks roughly like that:

```
class myLib
{
   public:
      myLib();
      ~myLib();
      void configWriter( unsigned long address, byte data );
      byte configReader( unsigned long address );
      File dbFile;
      EDB configDB;
}
```

...so far so good. But here comes the pain in the ... When I'm trying to instantiate a new EDB object in the constructor of my class by passing two pointers to the member functions I'm constantly getting an error. Here is how I call the constructor of the EDB library:

```
configDB = new EDB( &myLib::configWriter, &myLib::configReader );
```

I get the following error:

> no matching function for call to 'EDB::EDB()'
>
> [...] note: candidates are:
>
> note: EDB::EDB(void (*)(long unsigned int, uint8_t), uint8_t (*)(long
>   unsigned int))
>        EDB(EDB_Write_Handler *, EDB_Read_Handler *);

The prototype of the EDB constructor looks like this:

> EDB(EDB_Write_Handler *, EDB_Read_Handler *);

EDB_Write_Handler and EDB_Read_Handler are defined like so:

> typedef void EDB_Write_Handler(unsigned long, const uint8_t);
>   typedef uint8_t EDB_Read_Handler(unsigned long);

So I assume that my constructor call doesn't work because the functions that I'm passing are from a foreign class: (myLib::*) and not just (*)

I have no idea how to solve that problem. Does someone of you have any idea?

Thanks,
Andy

EDIT:
Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

myLib.h:

```
#ifndef myLib_h
#define myLib_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <EDB.h>

#define SD_CS 4
#define SD_SS 10

class myLib
{
  public:
    myLib();
    ~myLib();
    void begin();
    void configWriter( unsigned long address, byte data );
    byte configReader( unsigned long address );
    File dbFile;
    EDB * configDB;

};

#endif
```

myLib.cpp:

```
#include "myLib.h"

myLib::myLib( void )
{}

myLib::~myLib()
{}

void myLib::begin()
{
  // Init SD  
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  SD.begin(SD_CS);

  // Load Config
  configDB = new EDB( &myLib::configWriter, &myLib::configReader );
  dbFile = SD.open("config.db", FILE_WRITE);
}

void myLib::configWriter( unsigned long address, byte data )
{
  dbFile.seek(address);
  dbFile.write(data);
  dbFile.flush();
}

byte myLib::configReader( unsigned long address )
{
  dbFile.seek(address);
  return dbFile.read();
}
```

Arduino sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <EDB.h>
#include "myLib.h"

myLib* a;

void setup()
{
  a = new myLib();
  a->begin();
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it methods of an instance instead of the class?

Comment: new EDB( &this->configWriter, &this->configReader ); like so? already tried it. same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a common one with C++.  It basically boils down to how C++ handles member functions.

You define a member function as, say,

```
class myLib {
    void myFunc(int val);
};
```

When you call the function it's actually not defined as that - it's instead had its definition change to:

```
void myFunc(myLib *this, int val);
```

The addition of the `myLib *this` is an *implicit* parameter, and it's how C++ keeps track of its object instances when calling different functions.

So a function which expects a parameter of `void (*func)(int)` won't accept your method because it's actually `void (*func)(myLib *, int)`.  Hence the error you are seeing.

There is no easy, clean, way around it that I have found as yet, I am afraid.  The closest you can do is to move the reader and writer functions outside of your class and store a global pointer to the actual class, something like:

```
static myLib *globalLib;
void globalConfigWriter( unsigned long address, byte data ) {
    globalLib->congigWriter(address, data);
}
byte globalConfigReader( unsigned long address ) {
    return globalLib->configReader(address);
}
```

Then in the constructor for your lib you can do:

```
myLib::myLib() {
    globalLib = this;
}
```

You then register the global reader and writer functions with the EDB constructor instead of the class member functions.

It does have the rather major down-side that there can only be one instance of your class since there is only one global pointer and only one pair of reader / writer functions.  There are ways of supporting a finite number of instances, but it basically involves having a reader/writer pair for each instance and allocating one to an instance when it's constructed and de-allocating it when its destructed.  Keeping track of them and knowing which object is associated with which function pair is tricky at best...

Comment: Thanks, Majenko for your easy explanation! Now I can see where the problem is. Being able to create only one instance of the class isn't a problem in my case. I'll give your solution a try and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We don't care what the functions do, just make up an example that demonstrates the message.

---

Having said that, this looks wrong:

```
class myLib
{
   public:
      myLib();
      ~myLib();
      void configWriter( unsigned long address, byte data );
      byte configReader( unsigned long address );
      File dbFile;
      EDB configDB;
}
```

> Here is how I call the constructor of the EDB library:

```
 configDB = new EDB( &myLib::configWriter, &myLib::configReader );
```

OK so myLib is a **class**, not an **instance of a class**.

> The prototype of the EDB constructor looks like this:

```
    EDB(EDB_Write_Handler *, EDB_Read_Handler *);
```

So you want an **instance** of EDB_Write_Handler.

---

Let's say that EDB needed a dog and a cat. You don't pass "dog" and "cat" you pass "Fido" and "Fluffy". They are instances of the classes.

---

You have this:

```
configDB = new EDB( &myLib::configWriter, &myLib::configReader );
```

The constructor for EDB expects two functions:

```
EDB(EDB_Write_Handler *, EDB_Read_Handler *);
```

These are declared like this:

```
typedef void EDB_Write_Handler(unsigned long, const uint8_t);
typedef uint8_t EDB_Read_Handler(unsigned long);
```

These are **static** functions, that is, they cannot be class functions. Why not? Because a class function has an implicit pointer **this** which points to this instance of the class.

So, you cannot pass a non-static class-function to the EDB constructor.

Now you can make the functions configWriter and configReader static, but then they can't access class variables (eg. dbFile) because they belong to an **instance** of the function.

I've tried fiddling around with your code, but without a clear understanding of your intentions, I can't get it to compile. Do you mean to **derive** your class from EDB?

Why do you even want a class `myLib`? Are you planning to have multiple instances of it? If so, why? If not, why make a class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick! I'm quite familiar with the difference between a class and an instance (aka object) of a class but I'm a little unsure when it comes to the syntax of c++. Thanks for your suggestion! I've added a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: This is not at all an Arduino problem. It is a C++ problem.