# undefined reference to `PPMintIn::PPMintIn(int)'

Tags: arduino-uno, library, compile, avr-gcc

I am making a new library that will utilize PinChangeInt's library. 
My intention is to further simplify repetitive code by creating a library. (This is to allow for multiple PPM channels without rewriting a bunch of code for each channel i decide to add.)
Since i understand OOP i knew that i could go the route of make my own library.

The problem i'm having right now, is that the library is returning an undefined reference. The IDE i'm using is UECIDE with QTcreator on the side to help me with my syntax. The compiler is avr-gcc. The chip is an Arduino Uno. The problem i'm recieving is

> C:...\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2.cpp.o: In function '__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>   
> C:...\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2.ino:5: undefined reference to 'PPMintIn::PPMintIn(int)'
>   
> C:...\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2.cpp.o: In function 'setup':
>   
> C:...\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2.ino:9: undefined reference to 'PPMintIn::begin()'
>   
> Failed linking sketch

I tried to define the variables in my h and cpp files but it doesn't seem to be fixing the problem.

Here is the .ino code.

for some reason UECIDE can't see the Pinchange and PPMint libraries

```
#include "arduino.h"
#include "C:\Users\User\Documents\UECIDE\libraries\PinChangeInt\PinChangeInt.h"
#include "C:\Users\User\Documents\UECIDE\libraries\PPMintIn\PPMintIn.h"

PPMintIn CH1(A0);

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    CH1.begin();
}

void loop(){
}
```

Here is the .cpp code

```
#include "arduino.h"
#include "ppmintin.h"
#include "PinChangeInt.h"
//defined these
volatile int pwm_value = 0; 
volatile int prev_time = 0;
uint8_t latest_interrupted_pin = 0;

PPMintIn::PPMintIn(int pin){
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);\
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    _pin = pin;
}

void PPMintIn::rising(){
    PPMintIn::latest_interrupted_pin = PCintPort::arduinoPin;
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(latest_interrupted_pin, &rising, RISING);
    PPMintIn::pwm_value = micros()-PPMintIn::prev_time;
}

void PPMintIn::falling(){
    PPMintIn::latest_interrupted_pin=PCintPort::arduinoPin;
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(latest_interrupted_pin, &rising, RISING);
    PPMintIn::pwm_value = micros()-PPMintIn::prev_time;
}

void PPMintIn::begin(){
    PCintPort::attachInterrupt(_pin, &rising, RISING);
}

void PPMintIn::getSignal(){
    return(PPMintIn::pwm_value);
}
```

Here is the .h code

```
#ifndef PPMINTIN_H
#define PPMINTIN_H

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
  #else
  #include "WProgram.h"
#endif
#include "PinChangeInt.h"

class PPMintIn{
public:
    PPMintIn(int pin);
    void begin();
    void getSignal();
    int _pin;
    volatile int pwm_value;
    volatile int prev_time;
    uint8_t latest_interrupted_pin;
private:
    void rising();
    void falling();
};

#endif // PPMINTIN_H
```

here is the full thing in github in case I didn't supply it here. 
https://github.com/tisaconundrum2/PPMintIn

Comment: The IDE probably can't parse those full paths. Why are you using them instead of trusting that the IDE knows where the headers are?

Comment: because when i use the debug console included with IDE it can't find the files. It's only when i do the full paths, does it know what i want

Comment: Looking for header file C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2\libraries\PinChangeInt\PinChangeInt.h
Library.java 98 (<init>): 

Looking for header file :\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\RCRoomba_TestPulseV2\libraries\PPMintIn\PPMintIn.h
it just scrolls through this forever

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/awwtHKj.png

Comment: No, the *compiler* knows what you want. The *IDE* has no clue, so it doesn't include the libraries for compilation and linking.

Comment: the compiler does link to the library, however these libraries that it linked to are empty and have nothing in it.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what "linking" is. Especially given that the errors posted towards the top of this question are link errors.

Comment: Well alright, i did what you suggested, This is the outcome
http://i.imgur.com/W1gpqIh.png
And when i export both the libraries to see what's inside, they are basically empty new libraries

Comment: Now the IDE is doing the right thing. However, your "PPMintIn" library itself has errors that need to be fixed.

Comment: why is my library sitting with my INO file, i thought it should be going into the libraries folder.

Comment: You need to watch your capitalization as well - the Arduino header file is Arduino.h not arduino.h and your main header file (ppmintin.h) must have the same capitalization as your library folder (PPMintIn.h).  On operating systems with case sensitive filesystems it will completely break otherwise.

Comment: Which version of the IDE are you using, and how did you create the library in the first place?

Comment: It should be, right up until the IDE builds it. Then it copies everything into a single directory and builds it there.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/r0BSQD5.png

Comment: Also you should take a look at this, it will tell you why you are getting some of your errors: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/pass-a-member-function-pointer-to-a-method-of-a-foreign-class-edb-lib

Comment: I redid all of my code, and deleted a bunch of copies of the same library. Anyways, I'm getting less errors now. That should be a good thing but i'm getting this one error
http://i.imgur.com/ZIhuule.png

Comment: which doesn't make sense to me because the function allows for ints


PPMintIn::PPMintIn(int pin){
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);\
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    _pin = pin; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both Majenko and I tried to explain in [Pass a member function pointer to a method of a foreign class (EDB Lib)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/pass-a-member-function-pointer-to-a-method-of-a-foreign-class-edb-lib) you can't pass a class member function where a static function is expected.

---

Your error is on:

```C++
PCintPort::attachInterrupt(latest_interrupted_pin, &rising, RISING);
```

Error:

```
/home/nick/sketchbook/libraries/PPMintIn/ppmintin.cpp: In member function ‘void PPMintIn::rising()’:
/home/nick/sketchbook/libraries/PPMintIn/ppmintin.cpp:22: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&PPMintIn::rising’
```

---

PCintPort::attachInterrupt expects a `PCIntvoidFuncPtr` variable:

```C++
int8_t PCintPort::attachInterrupt(uint8_t arduinoPin, PCIntvoidFuncPtr userFunc, int mode)
```

That is:

```C++
typedef void (*PCIntvoidFuncPtr)(void);
```

That is a static function (not a class function).

However you have it as a class function:

```C++
class PPMintIn{
public:
    PPMintIn(int pin);
    void begin();
    void getSignal();
    int _pin;
    volatile int pwm_value;
    volatile int prev_time;
    uint8_t latest_interrupted_pin;
private:
    void rising();
    void falling();
};
```

Now you can make `rising` and `falling` static but now they can't access any of the class variables (eg. pwm_value, prev_time, latest_interrupted_pin).

The whole thing needs a redesign. You could try making PPMintIn a namespace rather than a class.

---

Regarding one of the comments:

[image: Error message]

Unless your class implements `operator()` this line doesn't make sense:

```C++
chan1(15);
```

---

*Please copy and paste error messages into the post, don't make people go to Imgur to find a screenshot of some text.*