# pass class internal function as callback

Tags: programming, c++, arduino-ide, class

I am trying to pass a class internal function as a callback function within the class. The error behavior is similar to [this problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/pass-a-member-function-pointer-to-a-method-of-a-foreign-class-edb-lib). Whatsoever, I was unable to construct working code based on that question's answer.

I try to pass over a callback function from within the class,in order to create a finite state machine, inspired by the examples I found on adafruit regarding multithreading. The idea is, that each state can call his successor. The class itself then represents the state machine and I just will call its update function.

While the following code does not resemble this utility, it resembles the problem in a minimal example (based on [this larger codepiece](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-3/put-it-all-together-dot-dot-dot)):

```
class MyClass
{
  const byte theAnswer = 42;
  void (*myCallback)();

  void setCallback(void (*callback)())
  {
    myCallback = callback;
  }

  public:

  void print_info()
  {
    Serial.println(theAnswer);
  }

  void call()
  {
    myCallback();
  }

   MyClass()
  {
    setCallback(&MyClass::print_info);
  }
};


MyClass AClassOfItsOwn();

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (! Serial); // Wait until Serial is ready
}

void loop() 
{
  AClassOfItsOwn.call();
  return;
}
```

I get the following error code returned:

> ...testscript.ino: In constructor 'MyClass::MyClass()':
>
> testscript:25: error: no matching function for call to
>   'MyClass::setCallback(void (MyClass::*)())'
>
> ```
>      setCallback(&MyClass::print_info);
>
>                                      ^
> ```
>
> ...\testscript.ino:25:41:
>   note: candidate is:
>
> ...\testscript.ino:6:12:
>   note: void MyClass::setCallback(void (*)())
>
> ```
>    void setCallback(void (*callback)())
>
>         ^
> ```
>
> ...\testscript.ino:6:12:
>   note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (MyClass::*)()'
>   to 'void (*)()'
>
> ...\testscript.ino:
>   In function 'void loop()':
>
> testscript:40: error: request for member 'call' in 'AClassOfItsOwn',
>   which is of non-class type 'MyClass()'
>
> ```
>    AClassOfItsOwn.call();
>
>                   ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1 no matching function for call to
>   'MyClass::setCallback(void (MyClass::*)())'

---

**fun times with polymorphism**

This is code we discussed during looking for a solution. I leave it here for future reference.

I tried creating an instance of this wrapper within the actual class to hold the callback, but that did not work either.

```
class CallbackWrapper
{
  void (*myCallback)();
  public:

  void call()
  {
    myCallback();
  }

  void setCallback(void (*callback)())
  {
    myCallback = callback;
  }
};

class MyClass : public CallbackWrapper
{
  const byte theAnswer = 42;
  public:

  void print_info()
  {
    Serial.println(theAnswer);
  }

   MyClass()
  {
    CallbackWrapper::setCallback(&MyClass::print_info);
  }
};
```

trying to store the callback function in a wrapping class (also not working, `'((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::CBW' does not have class type`)

```
class CallbackWrapper
{
  void (*myCallback)();
  public:

  void call()
  { myCallback(); }

  void setCallback(void (*callback)())
  { myCallback = callback; }
};

class MyClass 
{
  const byte theAnswer = 42;
  CallbackWrapper CBW();
  public:
  void print_info() { Serial.println(theAnswer); }
  void call() { CBW.call(); }
  MyClass()
  { CBW.setCallback(&MyClass::print_info); }
};
```

An update on why I want to change the callback function during runtime. Here I try to randomly change the callback function:

```
class MyClass 
{
  CallbackWrapper CBW();
  public:
  void do_this() { Serial.println("doing this"); }
  void do_that() { Serial.println("doing that"); }
  void call() 
  { 
    CBW.call();
    if (rand() > 0.5)
    {
      CBW.setCallback(&MyClass::do_this)
    }
    else
    {
      CBW.setCallback(&MyClass::do_that)
    }
  }
   MyClass()
  {  }
};
```

For discussion with Michail

```
class CallbackWrapper
{
  public:
  void (*myCallback)();
  void call()
  { myCallback(); }

  virtual void setCallback(void (*callback)())
  {  }
};

class MyClass : public CallbackWrapper
{
  public:
  void setCallback(void (*callback)())
    { myCallback = callback; }
  void do_this() { Serial.println("doing this"); }
  void do_that() { Serial.println("doing that"); }
  void call() 
  { 
    CallbackWrapper::call();
    if (rand() > 0.5)
    { setCallback(&MyClass::do_this); }
    else
    { setCallback(&MyClass::do_that); }
  }
   MyClass()
  {  }
};
```

Comment: A member function does not have the prototype that you think. It has a hidden parameter for "this". A static member function could work as callback function but then it could not access member data. You should consider using virtual instead. The callback setting is then done by sub-class and implementation of the virtual member function. The C++ run-time will do the dispatch depending on the instance.

Comment: OK, I tried a bit with virtual functions, but I cannot make it run (see latest addition of code failure). Could you provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/examples/Blink/CosaBlinkFSM/CosaBlinkFSM.ino and the FSM library https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/FSM.hh. The state is a callback style function.

Comment: Without addressing the polymorphism part of the question, I have a [post about calling an ISR from a class](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12983).

Answer (score 6):

Unless you specifically limit yourself to one single class for a callback (i.e., include the class name in the function pointer specification) then you can ONLY use `static` member functions as callbacks.

`static` member functions appear as a normal function, not a member function, so don't have the implied `MyClass *this` as a first parameter.

If you want to allow member functions that aren't `static` you will have to make use of *polymorphism* and have a single *base* class that all classes which provide a callback function will inherit from.  Then you limit the callback function pointer to be members of that base class.

It is possible to do it if you are happy to limit to just one class, though the syntax is rather cryptic:

```
class MyClass 
{
  const byte theAnswer = 42;
  void (MyClass::*myCallback)();

public:

  void call() {
    (this->*myCallback)();
  }

  void setCallback(void (MyClass::*callback)()) {
    myCallback = callback;
  }

  void print_info() {
    Serial.println(theAnswer);
  }

  MyClass() {
    setCallback(&MyClass::print_info);
  }
};
```

Using polymorphism you can only pass a callback function that is a member of the parent class, so it looks like that method may be out.

Comment: So, I tried creating a base class `CallbackWrapper` which has the callback functionality (`(*myCallback)()`, `setCallback()` and `call()`). I inherited MyClass from that base class. I tried to hook up my Callback using `CallbackWrapper::setCallback(&MyClass::print_info())`. Return is `no matching function for call to 'MyClass::setCallback(void (MyClass::*)())'`

Comment: I can't visualize what you are describing. Polymorphism is a tricky subject and easy to get wrong.

Comment: I abuse the edit question to post my futile try. (:

Comment: That's not abuse - that's what it's there for.  You're not using polymorphism in the right way - you need to think along the lines of an "interface" as Java has it.  I'll see about an example.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure even I can do it using polymorphism - it's incredibly tricky.  Can you have just one standard function name that will always be the callback function in a class?

Comment: I appended another code piece to explain why I want to change the callback during runtime. In my specific case, I think I could try with some tedious code refactoring I could e.g. define a class State, which will have an initialization (constructor) and an update() and an exit callback. All could be based on the same abstract base class, which I think is what you envisioned in the first place?

Comment: Callbacks with classes are an absolute nightmare to manage. If I must have one (say for an interrupt handler) it is always either static or an external wrapper function - never an instance member function. I am wondering if what you are trying to achieve is actually the best way to do what you want to do...

Comment: I think you are right; I will rethink how to do what I want to do. I could imagine I could find a better way to deal with this problem.

Comment: @Faultier I have finally found the right syntax for passing an internal member function within the same class, but you are limited to just the one class with that method.

Comment: seems almost right, but execution yields me ´request for member 'call' in 'AClassOfItsOwn', which is of non-class type 'MyClass()'´